# How celery allows different workers to perform the same task at the same time?

Tags: celery

Versions

```
Python 3.9.18

Name: celery
Version: 5.3.6

Name: Django
Version: 4.2.10
```

Below is my task code.

```
from celery import chain, group
from task.celery import app


@app.task
def fun1():
    print('test1')

@app.task
def fun2(x):
    print('test2')

@app.task
def fun3(x):
    print('test3')

def main():
    workflow = chain(fun1(), group(fun2.s(), fun3.s()))
    for i in [1,2,3,4]:
        workflow.apply_async(queue=f"test:{i}")
```

I started four workers on four hosts respectively.

```
#Host1
celery -A task worker -l info --queues=test:1
#Host2
celery -A task worker -l info --queues=test:2
#Host3
celery -A task worker -l info --queues=test:3
#Host4
celery -A task worker -l info --queues=test:4
```

When I called the main method, I found that all four workers only executed fun1, and the other two tasks were not executed.

I'm not sure what's wrong. How can I make it correctly perform this task on four workers at the same time?